# Putting tag inside div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below it's a tab consisting of objects from multidimensional array the problem is that i'm trying to add a show more button on every one of my paragraph but i am unable to add the `<a></a>` tags inside the `show-more div` im not sure if its because of the `textcontent` function can anyone explain why its not working? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]:"John", ["last-Name"]:"Doe", ["age"]:21, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shaork chop cupim sabrisket."};
var person2 = {["first-Name"]:"Paul", ["last-Name"]:"Logan", ["age"]:22, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork "};
var person3 = {["first-Name"]:"Sean", ["last-Name"]:"Kim", ["age"]:32, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky p"};
var person4 = {["first-Name"]:"Ken", ["last-Name"]:"Chow", ["age"]:12, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken h"};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Iterate through the Person Array
personArr.forEach((person,i) => {
   // `person` is the ith member of personArr
   var name = document.createElement('h4');
   var desc = document.createElement('p');
   var button = document.createElement('div');
    desc.className = "hideContent";
 button.className = "show-more";
   // Update the contents of your h3 element and add it to the fragment.
   name.textContent = ` ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
   desc.textContent = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
   button.textContent = ` "<a href="#">Show more</a>"`; // HERE------------------------------->
   frag.appendChild(name);
   frag.appendChild(desc);
   frag.appendChild(button);

});
// Add the fragment to the parent :)
parent.appendChild(frag);

$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    
    
    if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
        linkText = "Show less";
        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
    } else {
        linkText = "Show more";
        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
    };

    $this.text(linkText);
});
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
.size{
width:50%;
}
.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
.showContent{
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class ="size">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1"> 

 </div>
 </div>
</div>


     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string contains HTML, Use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`:

```
button.innerHTML = `<a href="#">Show more</a>`;
```

To use `switchClass()` you have to add the reference of jQueryUI and wrap the variable `$content` with jQuery:

```
$($content).switchClass(.....
```

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]:"John", ["last-Name"]:"Doe", ["age"]:21, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shaork chop cupim sabrisket."};
var person2 = {["first-Name"]:"Paul", ["last-Name"]:"Logan", ["age"]:22, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork "};
var person3 = {["first-Name"]:"Sean", ["last-Name"]:"Kim", ["age"]:32, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky p"};
var person4 = {["first-Name"]:"Ken", ["last-Name"]:"Chow", ["age"]:12, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken h"};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);


var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Iterate through the Person Array
personArr.forEach((person,i) => {
   // `person` is the ith member of personArr
   var name = document.createElement('h4');
   var desc = document.createElement('p');
   var button = document.createElement('div');
    desc.className = "hideContent";
 button.className = "show-more";
   // Update the contents of your h3 element and add it to the fragment.
   name.textContent = `${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
   desc.textContent = `${person['person-desc']}`;
   button.innerHTML = `<a href="#">Show more</a>`; // HERE------------------------------->
   frag.appendChild(name);
   frag.appendChild(desc);
   frag.appendChild(button);

});
// Add the fragment to the parent :)
parent.appendChild(frag);

$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    
    
    if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
        linkText = "Show less";
        $($content).switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
    } else {
        linkText = "Show more";
        $($content).switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
    };

    $this.text(linkText);
});
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
.size{
width:50%;
}
.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class ="size">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1"> 

 </div>
 </div>
</div>$content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
```

Comment: That worked do you have any idea why the show more button is still not working?

Comment: @Bobby, there is no `switchClass()` in JavaScript. You can remove then add class you want...

Comment: @Bobby, based on the code you have written on clicking the button only the text is changing from `Show more` to `Show less` and vice versa. Do you have another button or any other functionalities to implement???

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `textContent` to: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/GGxGrN

```
button.innerHTML = ` <a href="#">Show more</a>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is HTML,

```
button.innerHTML = ` <a href="#">Show more</a>`;
```

> you should use textContent when working with text and innerHTML when
>   manipulating the inner HTML of an element.
>
> If you try to add a  element using textContent, it will render it
>   as text. However, if you add a  element using innerHTML, it will be
>   rendered as HTML.

Updated code snippet with native toggle functionality

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]:"John", ["last-Name"]:"Doe", ["age"]:21, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shaork chop cupim sabrisket."};
var person2 = {["first-Name"]:"Paul", ["last-Name"]:"Logan", ["age"]:22, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork "};
var person3 = {["first-Name"]:"Sean", ["last-Name"]:"Kim", ["age"]:32, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky p"};
var person4 = {["first-Name"]:"Ken", ["last-Name"]:"Chow", ["age"]:12, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken h"};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Iterate through the Person Array
personArr.forEach((person,i) => {
   // `person` is the ith member of personArr
   var name = document.createElement('h4');
   var desc = document.createElement('p');
   var button = document.createElement('div');
    desc.className = "hideContent";
 button.className = "show-more";
   // Update the contents of your h3 element and add it to the fragment.
   name.textContent = ` ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
   desc.textContent = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
   button.innerHTML = `<a href="#">Show more</a>`; // HERE------------------------------->
   frag.appendChild(name);
   frag.appendChild(desc);
   frag.appendChild(button);

});
// Add the fragment to the parent :)
parent.appendChild(frag);

$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    
    
    if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
        linkText = "Show less";
//        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
        $content.addClass('hideContent').removeClass('showContent');

    } else {
        linkText = "Show more";
//        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
        $content.addClass('showContent').removeClass('hideContent');

    };

    $this.text(linkText);
});
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
.size{
width:50%;
}
.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
.showContent{
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class ="size">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1"> 

 </div>
 </div>
</div>


     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it worked Do you have any idea why my show more button doesn't work?

Comment: I have updated for toggle for `show more` and `show less` because `switchClass()` is a method of jquery UI .
What's the issue ?